# Mongodb connection with Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have created mongodb server with mongod command and it waits for connection at port 27017.
I am using java with eclipse to connect to it
Here is my code

```
package mt;

import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import com.mongodb.*;

public class mtrial {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            MongoClient mc = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            DB db = mc.getDB("mydb");
            System.out.println("Connected");   
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
        }
    }
}
```

MY PROBLEM is code runs succesfully  >>BUT<< in reality, connection doesnt take place... my server terminal keeps waiting for connections on port 27017....

Is there something that i am missing??

Comment: Have you tried accessing the mongo collections or writing data?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Your mongod server will accept many connections to port 27017, not just one.

Comment: when i use terminal as a client(using command ./mongo) it works.. But hwen i use java, its not getting connected

Comment: @Smutje i used it....code runs fine but no output..

Comment: Try to write something to the database through your java code, then check if succeeding by query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I know it works little different than other databases. When you try to actually access the collections operations (CRUD etc) then only you see connections request on the server.
You can try be giving wrong port number also you will not get exceptions untill you access collections operations. If you put lines 3, 4, 5 then you can see connection requests on the server

```
1. MongoClient c = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
2. DB db = c.getDB("test1");
3. DBCollection animals = db.getCollection("animals");
4. BasicDBObject animal = new BasicDBObject("animal", "monkey");
5. animals.insert(animal);
```

Comment: You are right...i observed that database.0 and database.ns doesnt get created until you use collection operations... these 2 files didnt appear at first though i had provided the <database>name as an arguement to getDB() method..... so i thought code isnt working....thanks